# Calculate unique integer identifier for elements in an hierarchical structure based on its position

Tags: algorithm

We have a hierarchical structure like this :

```
- 1 ( identifier = 100 )
  - 1 (101)
  - 2 (102)
  - 3 (103)
    - 1 (1031)
    - 2 (1032)
    - 3 (1033)
  - 4 (104)
    - 1 (1041)
    - 2 (1042)
    - 3 (1043)
  -901 (1001)
- 2 (200)
  - 1 (201)
  - 2 (202)
- 10 (1000)
  - 1 (1001)
```

Required characteristics :

- the identifiers of each node should be unique.
- the identifiers should increment accordingly to level of the element
- the identifiers should be of Integer type.
- the counter of each element resets at each new level/parent element

As you can see in the example of elements 1.901 and 10.1 , the current implementation doesn't work.
We've tried next solutions :

- multiplying each level by number.
- multiplying only the first level by a number and add each child

It becomes much more easier in case the identifier is a String, in this case we can use next way : "level1.level2.level3...", so for 1 -> 1 it will be "1.1" and so on. But this is the most unwanted step.

So, could you please suggest any algorithm that can be used here to generate required identifiers ?

**Update** Fixed the example. P.S. I knew that it's wrong.

Comment: I am not sure of what you mean with "the identifiers should increment accordingly to level of the element". Given that, what about using as indetifiers all numbers except the ones that contain a zero, and adding a zero every time you open a branch?

Comment: @flebool - this structure is read from xml. It's possible to restrict each element's number, but it's not the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your example is wrong (100 maps to identifier 10000), but this doesn't mean it works. Here"s why:

```
- 1 (100)
  -1 (101)
  ...
  -100 (200)
- 2 (200)
```

What you need to have a working example is indeed to **multiply each level by a number N** or to say the same, **reserve X digits for each level**. In your case, you chose `N = 100`, so the extra constraint you need to make your example work is that **each level cannot have more than `N-1` children**.

If you enforce this constraint, element 1.100 would be illegal, thus eliminating duplicate identifiers.

Using `N = 100` (or `X = 2`) could yield:

```
- 1 (01)
  - 1 (0101)
    - 1 (010101)
    ...
    - 3 (010103)
  ...
  - 99 (0199)
  - 100 is ILLEGAL
- 2 (02)
- 42 (42)
  - 42 (4242)
```

The "problem" then would be to **choose `X` wisely** so that you minimize the number of needed digits without constraining your user. For instance, if you know you will never add more than 450 children, choose `X=3`.

Comment: Updated the question. Your answer seems to be ok, except on thing : how to represent the difference between 1 and 10 ( 1 == 01, 10 == 10 ). As an Integer cannot start with 0, so I see only 1 way of preserving a fixed number of digits per row - multiplying by 10, 100... ?

Comment: Actually 1 is 1 and 10 is 10, you can ignore the leading zeros. What's important is that if a number has 1-2 digits it's in level 1, if it has 3-4 digits it's in level 2...

Comment: For example: if `X=3` and you have index `23017` then you "cut" it in three-digit parts starting from the end: `27 - 017`: you're in item `27`, subitem `17`.

Answer (score 3):

You're too hung up on decimal numbers.

1. Choose a value `X` which represents the maximum number of child nodes within a node, or any number greater than that that you find convenient to work with.
2. Drop your adherence to decimal numbers, and represent all identifiers as integers represented in base `X`.
3. Encode an identifier as an integer in base `X` where the first digit represents the top-level of the node tree, the second digit represents the second level, and so forth.

So, if you were lucky and a reasonable value for `X` turned out to be 16 you could use hexadecimal representations of integers.  If 36 is a good value, use any alphanumeric character as a digit.

**EDIT**

As Rafael has pointed out this approach breaks down if it is not possible to define an upper limit on the number of children a node can have.  In my experience this is unlikely to be a serious problem in practice.

If the value of `X` is large, say `863` then I'd suggest the obvious implementation would be to set `X = 1000` and use groups of 3 decimal digits to represent each digit in base `1000`.  This way the identifier `12.245.1` would be represented as `12245001`.

And now we're into territory already covered by alestanis' answer

Comment: The key insight here is that a requirement for your numbering system to work is that each node have an upper limit on the number of allowed subnodes. If you don't have an upper limit on the branching factor then your numbering system cannot be implemented - at least not as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has a simple but memory-wise costly solution:

Each node position can be easily represented as an unique finite sequence of integers i(1), i(2), ..., i(n):

- node 1 = [1]
- node 1.1 = [1, 1]
- node 7.2.42 = [7, 2, 42]

Thus the question can be represented as how to map each finite sequence of integers to a unique integer. That can be done using prime numbers

- p(1) = 2
- p(2) = 3
- p(3) = 5
- ...

Just multiply the i(n):th powers of primes p(n). The uniqueness of the resulting integer is guaranteed by the uniqueness of prime number factorization. See Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Examples:

- node 1 : 2^**1** = 2
- node 1.1 : 2^**1** * 3^**1** = 6
- node 7.2.42 : 2^**7** * 3^**2** * 5^**42** = (huge number!)

---

### Another possible solution

Begin with the string-representation of the node (e.g. "7.2.42"). Use octal numbers for node numbering. Use '8' (the first unused digit for octals) to separate levels instead of '.'. Use the resulting string as a decimal integer.

Examples:

- node 1 : 1
- node 1.1 : 181
- node 1.2 : 182
- node 1.3 : 183
- node 7.7.7 : 78787
- node 8 : 10
- node 8.1 : 1081
- node 8.2 : 1082
- node 8.9 : 10811
- node 8.9.1: 1081181
- node 8.9.2: 1081182

Comment: Yep, it works fine up to 6 levels, 100 elements each, but anyway it fits in this case only in Double, not in Integer.

Comment: No, this method produces an unique integer. However it doesn't meet all your specs: